# How to apply custom method to every incoming post or get variable in Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to apply my custom method to every incoming post or get variable, and modify it in some way. Where can i do that in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your bootstrap, add function:

```
 //eg. of trim all post params
 function _initHttpVars() {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $_POST[$key] = trim($value);
        }
    }
}
```